# IP tables rules which allows only the communicate with IP which are assigned

Tags: ip

I have ubuntu server with few vps running, mostly shared between friends and colleagues, it is from Hetzner,

I also have 2 set of ips ranging from 5.9.237.xxx to 5.9.237.xxx & 5.9.248.xxx to 5.9.248.xxx.

Today they locked my server due to different IP set on the VPS which is causing the problem, now i have KVM access, and they asked me to set up an IP TABLE rule which only allow to communicate the IP which are assigned and ignore the rest,

How to do this? Am a bit lost,

My OS is Ubuntu, and i want command that will ignore all the ips except the set of ip i give.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop all (careful with iptables, you can block yourself out)  you should learn how your distro handles them .. here are the command s that after a reboot will reset back to normal so temp to test.. .

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

or of course specify certain ips

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.10.10.118 -j ACCEPT
```

there is alot more to iptables then this but this should get you started